# Show/hide the content of the app based on a yes/no dropdown

Tags: android, html, show-hide

At the beginning of the app, there is a yes/no dropdown. If chosen "no", the rest of the code should not run and nothing should appear on the screen after the dropdown. If chosen "yes", the code written after (not shown here) should run. Is there a way to make this happen?

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FF8000"><h2>Solicitud de Vendedor Honorario</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Adiestramiento</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#1B4F72">
        <select id="yesno" size="1">
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Have you research Shared Preferences? You could apply an if statement at the very beginning of your code. If 1, carry out code, if 0 do nothing sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the value of the drop down, just set the css *display* property for whatever elements you want to hide to *none*.

Ex.

```
display: none;
```